# php script not updating mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a row in my database but it's not running.

Below is the current script I have that gets values from an ajax call.
I've checked the call and it is sending the right information.
know that I do have the connection values at the top of the script but did not include them here.

```
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
   if (!$connection) {
 die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}   // Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
  if (!$db_selected) {
die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// Store INFORMATION

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
    $csv = file_get_contents($request_url) or die("url not loading");
    $csvSplit = split(",", $csv);
    $status = $csvSplit[0];
    $lat = $csvSplit[2];
    $lng = $csvSplit[3];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $ident = $_POST['ident'];
 $query = "UPDATE  markers SET  name =  '".$name."', website =  '".$website."',address =  '".$address."',lat =  '".$lat."',lng =  '".$lng."',state =  '".$state."'WHERE id = '" . $ident . "'";
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

I'm still very new at this, can someone explain why it's not working?

Comment: is there any mysql error showing ?

Comment: What happens if you echo $query?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please post them.

Comment: Any errors in Apache logs? What do you mean by "it's not running" (the script isn't running? You get errors? the script runs but the database isn't changed????). Note also this is horribly vulnerable to SQL injection flaws (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, is the `id` column supposed to contain characters (as implied above) or integers?

Comment: @Ryan like I said I'm very new at this. where do I put the echo?

Comment: I don't see any error here, but you should escape all your input with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Hamish the script runs but the database isn't changed. Also can you recommend any good tutorials to prevent sql injection? the id is the unique identifier for the row, so an integer.

Comment: What happens when you call the php page directly (not using AJAX, but using a POST from a form?)? Does that work?

Comment: echo $query  and ensure you have valid where clause : `'WHERE id = '" . $ident . "'";`

Comment: If you don't know how you can see the output of your script, you can check it using Firebug on the "network" panel and filter it by "xhr". On  Ajax call, you'll see a new request here, click on the "+" button & response : voila, that's the output of your script

Comment: @poerg place echo $query; underneath where you define $query =  and copy / paste the output. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanKempt UPDATE  markers SET  name =  'Store Name', website =  'Website ',address =  'Address',lat =  '0',lng =  '0',state =  'Statedfdsf'WHERE id = ''

Comment: @poerg Ok your problem is $ident = $_POST['ident'];... this value is not being set or working properly. You can see this in that echo where it says WHERE id = ''.

Comment: @RyanKempt thanks after that I was able to discover some problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the field names like name, website and so on in this quotation marks: `
And you should only use one space between the words and maybe add a space before the WHERE.

Comment: I tried adding ` and field name and adding the space, but it's still not updating.

Comment: thank you, and Thanks  Ryan Kempt! Between the two of you I was able to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add space before 'where'

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` field is a number, you shouldn't be quoting the value you're comparing to, here:

```
WHERE id = '" . $ident . "'";
```

Just do this:

```
WHERE id = " . $ident;
```

One often overlooked test to to have your script echo out the actual query that's being run, and then take that query  string and run it directly against the database server - in your case, in phpMyAdmin against your MySQL server.

Comment: now I get this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1